# Short c#'s alternative to Java's Path.ResolveSibling. Unpossible?

Tags: java, c#, file, path, resolve

I have a filePath `string filePath = @"C:\MyDir\MySubDir\myfile.ext";` and another file name `string file2 = "otherfile.txt"`. Say I would like to get another file path `string filePath2 = @"C:\MyDir\MySubDir\otherfile.txt";` .

Is there a method in c# to create such filePath2?

In Java the method is

[Path resolveSibling(Path other)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolveSibling(java.nio.file.Path)%20Resolve%20sibling)

> Resolves the given path against this
>   path's parent path. This is useful where a file name needs to be
>   replaced with another file name. **For example, suppose that the name
>   separator is "/" and a path represents "dir1/dir2/foo", then invoking
>   this method with the Path "bar" will result in the Path
>   "dir1/dir2/bar"**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this (*combining* 1st file's *directory name* and the 2nd *file name*):

```
  string filePath = @"C:\MyDir\MySubDir\myfile.ext";
  string file2 = "otherfile.txt";

  // C:\MyDir\MySubDir\otherfile.txt
  string result = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath), file2);
```